# rm -rf doesnt show any errors but doesnt delete any files VS Code

Tags: javascript, bash, visual-studio-code, command

Heyo!I tried to google this but i couldnt find any answers anywhere.

I'm using Windows 10 and i've installed git bash and launched the bash terminal on visual studio code and all the commands that work on linux work on my bash terminal for now except the command rm-rf.

Everytime i use rm -rf, no errors are shown but no directories or folders are deleted. Everything just remains the same? What can i do to fix this? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQbUb.png)

UPDATE: ive figured out what went wrong. im supposed to specify a directory and not be INSIDE the directory for it to be removed. sorry for such a dumb question, thanks everyone!

Comment: `rm` removes each specified file.

Comment: You can try the verbose mode like: `rm -rf -v`

Comment: try `rm -rf ./*`

Comment: I suggest you delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly fine from my end.

There could be chances that you dont have **delete permission**. Try to give access then try it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the argument *what* to delete, e.g. `rm -r *` or `rm -rf *` to delete all files and directories recursively (ignoring hidden files) or just `rm *` to delete all non-hidden files.

The `-f` ignores nonexistent files and arguments and prevents an error message you would see without this option. You should rarely need `-f`, use it only when deleting  fails without it.

Answer (score 0):

i just had this problem, and it took me a little while to find the issue.

my task was supposed to remove all files under `TestResults`.

i had made a task with `"type": "process"`, which does not work for this. the task MUST be `"type": "shell"`.

here's one that works:

```json
{
    "label": "remove test results",
    "detail": "removes the files in the TestResults folder that coverage uses",
    "type": "shell",
    "group": "test",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": false
    },
    "command": "rm",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/TestResults"
    },
    "args": [
        "*",
        "-f"
    ]
},
```